# Modelling a Propositional Formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, mathematical-modeling, finite-state-machine

Considering the following finite state automata:

Finite State Automata Image - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adf2T.png)

Model the transition relation using the formula:
model = (a → b') ∧ (b → c') ∧ (c → b')

Now, Model as a propositional formula the property that the initial state a cannot be reached from c or b.

I am clear on the steps of propositional logic but the use of a finite automata in this has really thrown me off and as such, I am not sure how to attempt this?

Any help of tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why in the formula b' and c' ?

Comment: Maybe $\lnot (b \to a) \land \lnot (c \to a)$ ...

Comment: In regards to the why b'c and c'.

That is the next state of the automata, so what states can be reached by it and put into a set.

Comment: But why c' ? in the machine state diagram, we have c...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It looks as though these formulas are intended to be in some sort of temporal logic, using primes to mean "at the next time step".